# How to get a single value when parsing tensorflow/keras dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When parsing a tf dataset, you may use something like

```
def parse_example(x):
    return parse_example(
                x,
                {feature: tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
                 for feature in features
                 }
            )
```

This will return a dict (e.g., `dic={a:1, b:2, c:3}`, however, is there a way to get a single value of the dict (e.g., `dic[a] = 1`)?

Answer (score 0):

If 'a' is a key in the dict, you can retrieve its value by passing it enclosed in quotes:

`dic["a"]`

Comment: Then I got `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Could not parse example input, value: '...'
  [[{{node ParseExample/ParseExampleV2}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]`

Comment: @JohnM. Are you sure it is a dict? What does `type(dict)` tell you?